# dataframe export to json different precision of columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have following dataframe `df`:

```
     latitude  longitude                time    t2m   u10   v10
357     31.01      26.46 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.41 -0.27  2.38
358     31.01      26.52 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.42 -0.30  2.31
359     31.01      26.58 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.37 -0.32  2.18
360     31.01      26.64 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.32 -0.29  2.02
361     31.01      26.70 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.31 -0.23  1.85
362     31.01      26.76 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.35 -0.17  1.69
363     31.01      26.82 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.44 -0.07  1.55
364     31.01      26.88 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.55  0.05  1.42
365     31.01      26.94 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.65  0.17  1.31
366     31.01      27.00 2021-02-07 01:00:00  14.72  0.28  1.18
```

I want to create json from `df`. I am using following function:

```
def df_to_geojson(df, properties, lat='latitude', lon='longitude'):
    geojson = {'type':'FeatureCollection', 'features':[]}
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        feature = {'type':'Feature',
                   'properties':{},
                   'geometry':{'type':'Point',
                               'coordinates':[]}}
        feature['geometry']['coordinates'] = [row[lon],row[lat]]
        for prop in properties:
            feature['properties'][prop] = row[prop]
        geojson['features'].append(feature)
    return geojson
```

Now, for using function:

```
df=df.round(2)
cols = ['t2m','u10','v10']
geojson = df_to_geojson(df, cols)
```

As an output i get geojson:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "t2m": 14.41,
        "u10": -0.27000001072883606,
        "v10": 2.380000114440918
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          26.46,
          31.01
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {.........
```

Somehow, columns `u10` and `v10` are given in json in different precision. How can I get them i rounded to 2 like `t2m` column?

Comment: Have you saved it as json()? In the json file does the precision there?

Comment: I have saved it as .geojson. precision is same there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code with the example provided, and I don't see any extra digits in the output. Note that what your function produces is not actually JSON (which would be a string), but a `dict`. Thus, the `float` values in the `dict` are really `float`, not `str` representations of them. Depending on how you display the content of the `dict`, you may then suffer from the known [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Here are some suggestions.

1. Slight rewrite of the `dict`-producing function.

```py
def to_georecord(props, geom):
    return {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': props,
            'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': list(geom.values())}}

def to_geodict(df, props=('t2m', 'u10', 'v10'), geom=('longitude', 'latitude')):
    return {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [
        to_georecord(p, g) for p, g in zip(
            df[list(props)].to_dict('records'),
            df[list(geom)].to_dict('records'))]}
```

2. Use it as a `dict`

```py
>>> to_geodict(df.round(2))
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'t2m': 14.41, 'u10': -0.27, 'v10': 2.38},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [26.46, 31.01]}},
  {'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'t2m': 14.42, 'u10': -0.3, 'v10': 2.31},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [26.52, 31.01]}},
   ...
```

3. Use it as a JSON (string)

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(to_geodict(df.round(2)), indent=2))
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "t2m": 14.41,
        "u10": -0.27,
        "v10": 2.38
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          26.46,
          31.01
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that my dataframe data is faulty in some way. I did df['u10']=df['u10']+1,1 and df['u10']-1,1  . After that everything worked fine.